# Excluir clausulas en SQL (Código Dinámico SQL)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo un problema, una consulta, a ver, tengo un código java que ejecuta un `SELECT` a una BD, en el codigo se tiene lo siguiente:

```
if(serviciosDTO.getFechaInicio().length()>0)  
    sql = sql+" And tpe167.fh_fecha_servicio between :fechaInicio AND :fechaFin ";  
if(serviciosDTO.getServicios() > 0)  
    sql = sql+" And tpe138.cd_id_tipo_cliente =:serv ";  
if(reporteBitacoraServiciosDTO.getCdIdEstatusServicioCatel() > 0)  
    sql = sql+" And tpe167.cd_id_estatus_servicio_catel = :idEstatus";  
if(reporteBitacoraServiciosDTO.getCdIdMotivoLlamadaCatel() > 0)  
    sql = sql+ " And tpe165.cd_id_motivo_llamada_catel = :idMotivo";
```

Come ven en ese código se concatena en el sql los `AND` siempre y cuando vengan esos datos informados, esos `AND` van después del `WHERE`. Ahora ese `SELECT` en código va a ir a un store de SQL Server, como hago en SQL para excluir esos `AND` cuando no estén informados los datos(Que se informan como argumentos de entrada al SP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una alternativa, supongo es algo nosql, se trata de código dinámico desde un SP, se declara una variable con todo el sql y las partes dinámicas según las variables se van concatenando. Quedaría algo así:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Tabla_1'
IF @varFechaInicio IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL = ' WHERE fecha_servicio = ' + @varFechaInicio
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Listo así se ejecuta la consulta con `WHERE` en caso de que la variable `@varFechaInicio` no sea nula.